# $f(z)$ be analytic define on $E=\{z:|z-2i|<3\}$ and $f(z)\ne 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f(z)$ be analytic define on $E=\{z:|z-2i|<3\}$ and $f(z)\ne 0$ I have some confusion

1. Then  does $|f|$ attains Maxima on $\partial E$? Not I think if I take $f(z)={1\over z+i}$ which is not even analytic at $z=-i\in \partial E$
2. If $f$ is analytic on $\partial E$ too. Then $|f|$ attains Maxima on $\partial E$? Yeah! by Maximum Modulas Theorem.
3. If $f$ is analytic on $E$ and continuous on $E\cup \partial E$
   Then continous function on compact set attain maxima and minima but my question is where? on $\partial E$?
4. $f$ is analytic on $E\cup \partial E$ and $f\ne 0$ then $|f|$ attain minima on $\partial E$? okay If I go back to $2$, Then This contradicts! so $4$ is wrong? but I am not sure here. Thank you for discussion any.

Comment: In your point (1) you answer yourself: that example is **not** analytic in the given domain....

Answer (score 1):

1. $\lvert f\rvert$ attains its maximum on $\partial E$ *if* $f$ *extends to a continuous function on* $\overline{E}$. If it doesn't extend continuously to the boundary, you can't in general assume that $\lvert f\rvert$ even has a value in a single boundary point, so you can't in general say that $\lvert f\rvert$ attains its maximum on the boundary. For functions like your example, that have a pole on the boundary and extend meromorphically to a neighbourhood of $\overline{E}$, it is not much of a stretch to say that $\lvert f\rvert$ attains its maximum value ($+\infty$) in the pole,hence on the boundary, but a maximum value of $+\infty$ doesn't give you much to work with, so the value of extending the notion to this situation is questionable.
2. If $f$ is analytic on $\overline{E}$, that means it's analytic in a neighbourhood of $\overline{E}$, it is in particular continuous on the compact set $\overline{E}$, so $\lvert f\rvert$ attains its maximum at some point of $\overline{E}$. If $\lvert f\rvert$ has a local maximum in $E$, $f$ is constant (since $E$ is connected), and hence $\lvert f\rvert$ attains its maximum also in every boundary point.
3. Like 2. $\lvert f\rvert$ attains its maximum certainly in some boundary point, and possibly (if $f$ is constant) also in interior points.
4. More generally, if $f$ extends continuously to the boundary, then either $\lvert f(z)\rvert > \min \{\lvert f(w)\rvert : w \in \partial E\}$ for all $z \in E$,, $f$ is constant $\neq 0$, or $f$ has a zero in $E$. For if $0 < \lvert f(z_0)\rvert \leqslant \min \{\lvert f(w)\rvert : w \in \partial E\}$, and $f$ has no zero in $E$, then $1/f$ is holomorphic in $E$, extends continuously to the boundary (since by assumption the extension has no zeros on the boundary), and

   $$\left\lvert \frac{1}{f(z_0)}\right\rvert \geqslant \max \left\lbrace \left\lvert \frac{1}{f(w)}\right\rvert : w \in \partial E\right\rbrace,$$

   so by the maximum principle $1/f$ is constant, hence $f$ is constant.